# License expression for commercial nuget package

Tags: msbuild, nuget, nuget-package, nuget-server

I'm uploading a private nuget package to a private nuget repository. The package is commercial (not open source).

The csproj has this:

```xml
<PackageLicenseExpression>Commercial</PackageLicenseExpression>
```

I receive a build warning that the above is not a valid "license expression".

What value do I use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to embed your license file, you can't use the license expression: https://learn.microsoft.com/nuget/reference/msbuild-targets#packing-a-license-expression-or-a-license-file

```xml
<PropertyGroup>
    <PackageLicenseFile>LICENSE.txt</PackageLicenseFile>
</PropertyGroup>

<ItemGroup>
    <None Include="licenses\LICENSE.txt" Pack="true" PackagePath=""/>
</ItemGroup>
```

NuGet's license expressions use [SPDX identifiers](https://spdx.org/licenses/), and I don't see any "generic" commercial license.